# How to optimally implement locking that queues access to specific part of data?

Tags: .net, synchronization, conflict, synclock

My ASP.NET application provides access to various chunks of data. Each chunk can be accessed by one or more users simultaneously, so the app must prevent conflicts.

After a lot of consideration, I'm thinking that optimistic concurrency is not the best solution for this scenario and currently looking at locking as a suitable option.

I can easily make all requests process one by one by using a `SyncLock` as follows:

> Private Shared AccessLock As New Object
>
> ```
>  SyncLock AccessLock
>
>  ..Do some reading and writing here
>
>  End Synclock
> ```

But that greatly limits the scalability of the application.

So I'm thinking of somehow enqueuing access to specific parts of data only. E.g. one queue is for accessing one part of data, and another queue for another part of data.

Is there a way to customize synchronization locking to use different queues for different parts of the data instead of just 1 queue for everything? I mean that it could allow me to manually specify something like "SyncLock ("Group1") and "SyncLock ("Group2").

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to customize synchronization locking to use different queues for different parts of the data instead of just 1 queue for everything? I mean that it could allow me to manually specify something like "SyncLock ("Group1") and "SyncLock ("Group2").

Yes.  You could have two separate objects, and `SyncLock` on the "Group1" object or the "Group2" object.

However, I would rethink your design.  You may want to consider having one or more `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)` collections to hold your data.  This will potentially let multiple threads access the data without taking locks, while remaining thread safe.

Comment: How could they simultaneously access the same data while still being thread safe?

Comment: @usr They could use the same collection, since ConcurrentQueue is thread safe itself.  The individual data elements would be processed by individual threads, though.  Shared data (between threads) would require synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your objects into groups, each of which you protect with a separate lock. This is called lock striping.

If you need to access more than one lock at a time you need to acquire them always in the same order or else you will get deadlocks.